# Password validation fails in two opposed scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, bcrypt, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and have generated an interesting dilemma. I will have done something wrong, so I need your help finding the issue.

The issue surrounds the validation of a password property within a `User` model. The initial validation of this property was:

```
validates :password,  presence: true, 
                        confirmation: true, 
                        length: { minimum: 6 }
```

This requires a minimum length of the password and is designed to satisfy the situation where a new user creates their instance.

I have created the following tests (and I wish I had used Rspec!) guided by the book. These tests check that the validations work:

```
test "password must not be blank or made up of spaces" do
  @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " "
  assert_not @user.valid?
end

test "password must not be empty/nil" do
  @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = ""
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

So, we’re checking that the password field cannot contain either a space, or a nil entry. With the current validations, these tests pass. All is well.

I have progressed to allowing a user to edit their profile. This enables the user to change their name, email address and password/confirmation if they choose. In order to allow a user *not* to change their password if they don’t want to, additional validation is added to the password property of the model, adding `allow_blank: true` such as:

```
validates :password,  presence: true, 
                      confirmation: true, 
                      length: { minimum: 6 }, 
                      allow_blank: true # added this!
```

So, the user can now leave the two password fields blank when they edit their profile if they don’t want to change their profile. This satisfies the test:

```
test "successful edit" do
  log_in_as @user
  get edit_user_path(@user)
  assert_template 'users/edit'
  name = "Foo Bar"
  email = "foo@valid.co.uk"
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: name,
                                            email: email,
                                            password: "",
                                            password_confirmation: "" } }
  assert_not flash.empty?
  assert_redirected_to @user
  @user.reload
  assert_equal @user.name, name
  assert_equal @user.email, email
end
```

This enables a user to edit just their name & email and, by leaving their two password fields blank, there’s no need to change, or re-enter, their `password`. This throws a FAIL on a long passing test, as above, such as:

```
test "password must not be blank or made up of spaces" do
  @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " "
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

The test fails because the user is validated. The slightly different test, which tests for `nil`, not blank, passes:

```
test "password must not be empty/nil" do
  @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = ""
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

So a password of `“”` is caught but a password of `“ “` works fine for creating a new user or editing an existing user.

Adding `allow_blank: true` to the user model validation of password seems to have caused this. So, I am stuck between two tests failing. If I omit `allow_blank: true`, this test fails (full test pasted above):

```
test "successful edit" do
.
.
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: 
                                    { name: name,
                                      email: email,
                                      password: "",
                                      password_confirmation: "" } }
.
  assert_equal @user.name, name
  assert_equal @user.email, email
end
```

Sending the blank `password` and `password_confirmation` fails the test as it isn’t allowed to be blank.

Adding `allow_blank: true` within the validation fails this test:

```
test "password must not be blank or made up of spaces" do
  @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " "
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

This fail allows a user to be created with a password consisting of spaces. A `nil` password, i.e. no characters at all, is not allowed. That test works.

This leaves me in the position where I must decide between a user having to change/repeat their two password fields if they edit their profile, OR, allowing a scenario where a user can sign up with a password consisting of one space, or many spaces, as this test doesn’t throw the expected failure message:

```
test "password must not be blank or made up of spaces" do
   @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " "
   assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

The addition of `allow_blank: true` bypasses this test or the validation generally. A `password` of any number of spaces is accepted which is against the validation in the model. How is that possible?

Any thoughts how to test better (apart from using Rspec!). I bow to your greater knowledge.

TIA.

[EDIT]

The suggested changes in the comments below made my test suite green. This was due to the suite being inadequate. To test the unsuccessful integration, the suggested code tested multiple scenarios in one go, such as:

```
test "unsuccessful edit with multiple errors" do
  log_in_as @user
  get edit_user_path(@user)
  assert_template 'users/edit'
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: 
                                    { name: "",
                                      email: "foo@invalid",
                                      password: "foo",
                                      password_confirmation: "bar" } }
  assert_template 'users/edit'
  assert_select 'div.alert', "The form contains 3 errors."
end
```

The key part here is getting the number of expected errors correct so that `assert_select` gives the right result. I didn't. The errors should be blank name, invalid email format, password too short, pwd & confirmation don't match. The error for short password isn't showing.

I decided to pull out two more tests to demonstrate the failure of the validations of password length and presence. The point of `allow_blank` is to allow the password & confirmation fields to have *nothing* in them when editing the user profile so it isn't compulsory to enter the password every time the user profile is edited. These tests are:

```
test "unsuccessful edit with short password" do
  log_in_as @user
  get edit_user_path(@user)
  assert_template 'users/edit'
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: 
                                    { name: @user.name,
                                      email: "foo@valid.com",
                                      password: "foo",
                                      password_confirmation: "foo" } }
  assert_select 'div.alert', "The form contains 1 error."
end

test "unsuccessful edit with blank (spaces) password" do
  log_in_as @user
  get edit_user_path(@user)
  assert_template 'users/edit'
  patch user_path(@user), params: { user: 
                                    { name: @user.name,
                                      email: "foo@valid.com",
                                      password: " ",
                                      password_confirmation: " " } }
  assert_select 'div.alert', "The form contains 1 error."
end
```

If the password *is* changed, then the validation rules should apply, i.e. the password should not be blank and must have a minimum length. That's not what's happening here either in the code the Tutorial book suggests or the amended code using `on: :create` and `on: :edit`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123972/ruby-on-rails-password-validation  consider the answer on this question.

Comment: There are some alternative implementations in that question, @MisterCal. As well as trying to find a workable solution, OP also posed the problem that the existing validation of a minimum length and non-blankness are overridden by the addition of `allow_blank: true` at a point in the code where `BCrypt` should be capturing non-blankness for new users. Indeed, the `update` action isn't bypassing the validation as a new user will (should!) have adhered to the validation rules and have a validated pwd. So, how does this addition allow a new user to be created contrary to the validation rules?

Comment: you only specify the the statement `on: :create`.  And then create another validation which does not have the `allow_blank` statement `on: :edit`.

Comment: Hi, OnlySteveH. Thanks for pinging me on the other thread. Have you tried what @MisterCal has suggested? Sounds about right to me.

Comment: Hi @jvillian I hadn't managed to get that to work as yet but I think I understand the workaround presented. My main concern is how the existing validation is sidestepped, and why `BCrypt` isn't picking this up. I guess my validations are somewhat contradictory so defining different rules for different controller actions does make sense to a large extent so I will give that a go later. The key learning, for me, is why does this code cause the validation to 'fail' and is there an order of precedence for these rules?

Comment: I've now implemented the change and having two sets of validations for `:edit` and `:create` is working fine - by that, I mean the test suite is green. Thanks, @MisterCal. I'd like to get an understanding of the error, though, especially given that the Rails Tutorial book doesn't have this as an issue. A clearer understanding of _why_ my code behaved as it did would allow me to move on.

Comment: I was thinking about this last night when I couldn't sleep, sadly! The green suite was due to the tests being inadequate, not because the problem had been solved. I've edited my question above to reflect the changes I have made to the test suite and to articulate the problem. A user can enter a short password or a password made of spaces when they edit their profile - the validation works fine on user creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out so am posting here in case others come across a similar problem.

I amended the validations to include the `:update` action on the `User`, rather than just `:edit`. This covered the action of saving to the database and caught the short password update validations but still allowed passwords made of spaces.

A bit of checking the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil) showed me that using `allow_blank: true` *allows* `nil` and strings made up of spaces. The scenario here wants a `nil` password to be acceptable, but not a blank one. The alternative validation of `allow_nil: true` is more appropriate to the scenario here.

The updated code from above looks like, in `User.rb`:

```
validates :password,  presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 6 }, 
                      allow_nil: true, 
                      on: [:edit, :update]

validates :password,  presence: true, 
                      confirmation: true, 
                      length: { minimum: 6 }, 
                      on: :create
```

The extended test suite is now all green.