# Ruby on Rails ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and am coming across an error which says, in full: `ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"steve@example.com", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]`

This relates to code allowing the user to reset their password from a form. The error refers to a route, so I'll start there with `routes.rb`:

```
get 'sessions/new'

root    'static_pages#home'
get     '/about',     to: 'static_pages#about'
get     '/contact',   to: 'static_pages#contact'
get     '/help',      to: 'static_pages#help'

get     '/signup',    to: 'users#new'
post    '/signup',    to: 'users#create'
get     '/login',     to: 'sessions#new'
post    '/login',     to: 'sessions#create'
delete  '/logout',    to: 'sessions#destroy'

resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

The error mentions the `edit` action which is blank within the controller. The reset functionality is produced from the `create` action in the `password_resets_controller` like:

```
def create 
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
  if @user
    @user.create_reset_digest
    @user.send_password_reset_email
    flash[:info] = "Email sent with reset instructions"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Email address not found"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
end
```

This pulls the user from the database using the email submitted on the form. Then calls two methods from the model to walk through the reset process. First, the `create_reset_digest` method which creates a token and updates the attributes for that user:

```
def create_reset_digest
  self.activation_token = User.new_token # <- error here; wrong attribute
  update_attributes(reset_digest: User.digest(reset_token), 
                    reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
end
```

Then, it sends the password reset email:

```
def send_password_reset_email
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
end
```

In the email, there is mention of the `edit_password_reset_url` which I think is the cause of this error. The view for that email is:

```
<%= link_to "Password reset", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, 
                                                      email: @user.email) %>
```

This method takes the user's reset token and email and presents this in a url that the user can visit to reset their password. The url takes the form `http://example.com/password_resets/reset_token/edit?email="steve%40example.com"`

The error implies that there's a constraint that remains unmatched; that the `[:id]` isn't matched - indeed, it is shown to be `nil`. Where does that `:id=>nil` come from and how can I get it to match to, presumably, the user id? Can I imply anything else from the error message?

I am getting this error when I run a rudimentary test:

```
test "password_reset" do
  @user.activation_token = User.new_token
  mail = UserMailer.password_reset(@user)
  assert_equal "Password reset",        mail.subject
  assert_equal ["to@example.org"],      mail.to
  assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
  assert_match "Hi",                    mail.body.encoded
end
```

When I use the web app to fire the password reset, I get a slightly different error in that it is a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PasswordResets#create`. This highlights the `edit_password_reset_url((@user.reset_token, email: @user.email)` method. I've checked in the book and can't see that this line is incorrect.

Your advice is welcomed.

Comment: Where do you set `@user.reset_token` (used in `link_to`)? I see something like `self.activation_token = User.new_token`. But not something like `self.reset_token = ...`.

Comment: Thanks @jvillian! That's what happens when I blindly cut & paste methods. You're absolutely correct - I was setting `self.activation_token` and not ```self.reset_token`. So, presumably, `reset_token` was `nil`. Anyway; I've changed that part of the code and all seems fine. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Glad to help. I added as an answer in case you care to upvote/accept.

Comment: Done! :) All up-votes help, right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you do not set `@user.reset_token` (used in `link_to`)? I see something like `self.activation_token = User.new_token`. But not something like `self.reset_token = ....`.

Comment: could you look at another outstanding question I have on here, if you have a minute. TIA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105824/password-validation-fails-in-two-opposed-scenarios